# How can I tell exactly what keys are being pressed on the Mac?

Tags: keyboard

At the moment I'm trying to remote control my machine and command and ctrl do not seem to be working properly.  Is there some type of 'keyboard sniffer' functionality so I can see exactly what is and is not being received?

Comment: I was looking for the same thing, It's called "keystroke visualizer".

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I don't know if the built-in keyboard viewer is sophisticated enough, but it should highlight pressed keys.

[image]

If you do not see those options, make sure it is checked off under your **System Preferences > Keyboard**

[image]

There are also apps like [Keycastr](https://github.com/keycastr/keycastr) that display bezel elements for pressed keys.

Comment: no need in terminal. need octal/hex numbers. otherwise you don't know what is being sent.

Comment: In 10.15.5 this checkbox appears to be moved to Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources -> "Show Input menu in menu bar"

Answer (score 25):

The application [Key Codes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) from [Many Tricks](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/), available for free from the App Store, displays the key code, unicode value, and modifier keys state for any key combination pressed on your computer. If you need more extensive information than that provided by the Keyboard Viewer, you might find it helpful.

Comment: I tried Key Codes and it doesn't work for media keys.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to debug a firmware of int'l keyboard.

Comment: Let's try on macOS.

Comment: As @epx highlights, this is very helpful for alternative keyboard layouts, including Dvorak.

Comment: For my CLoudnine C959 Egotkl gaming keyboard it doesn't show what I need to change. But it looks like no apps do.

Answer (score 7):

[Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) includes an Event Viewer that works really well. For example, Apple's Keyboard Viewer just ignores keypad keys; Karabiner-EventViewer shows them.

Comment: I needed to log which keys are pressed during my daily usage so I know whether I really need a numpad or not. This was very useful for that. Although it does not directly give stats, it allows me to copy it to clipboard. I can then hopefully generate a summary using a program. Thanks.

Comment: Update: Karabiner Elements only gives the last 10 or so keypresses. Can't use it for this.