# How to press Control key on Mac

Tags: terminal, keyboard

I cannot seem to find out how to hit the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key on a Mac. When I open a terminal and I want to exit an editor such as nano as I cannot since I don't know how to exit and save. How would I do this? I am using OS X 10.5.

Comment: What happens if you type the ctrl key?

Comment: Please, tell me this is not a "I can't find the 'any' key".

Comment: Make sure the Control Key is enabled in System Preferences / Keyboard / Keyboard / Modifier Keys.

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40192/how-can-i-tell-exactly-what-keys-are-being-pressed-on-the-mac

Comment: @Michiel I **think** he is asking how to exit or save while using the editor nano inside Terminal. Really kinda need the OP to clarify as the question is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 13):

Different keyboard layouts have used different labels on the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd> key. It might be marked `control` or `CTRL` or even `^`. Additionally, the behavior of that key can be easily reassigned using **System Preferences**, which means that the control key on your keyboard could be remapped to do something else (or nothing); if you are not getting results when you post, that could be the problem.

[image]

I've created an [instructional video](http://youtu.be/oC3h5YBLtSw) on how to press the control key on a mid-2011 MacBook Air.

Answer (score 1):

When working in the editor **nano** (within Terminal) your **ctrl key
combinations** are listed at the bottom of said terminal window.

> **NOTE:** The following key combinations consist of **only letters**.

**The key combinations you are searching for are:**

**<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> =  Save** (Will provide a prompt to chose name to save as)

**<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> = Exit**

**Other popular combinations while on the standard nano editor are:**

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> = Get Help

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> = Read file (Insert file from specific location)

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> = Cut Text (Will cut the entire line of text that your cursor is on)

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> = Where Is (Search current **nano** page)

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> = Current Position (Locates the current position your cursor is on and reports the line column and character)

Comment: The OP implies that they already know how to do this.

Comment: @JasonSalaz The question is very confusing in how it is worded.

Comment: @JasonSalaz I apologize I interpreted *I don't know how to exit and save* to say that the OP didn't know.

Comment: But all the sentences before that involve the inability to use the `Ctrl` key, which Nano leverages heavily, which you also point out in this post.

Comment: @JasonSalaz :–) It just reminded me of when my little brother got stuck in nano and couldn't figure out how to exit. :–D

Answer (score 1):

I understand the problem. For me, my Mac mapped the control key to Mission Control. Open up Mission Control in Settings, and disable the control key. That's it. The Control key will work now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever done a ^c to exit a program? It's the same key that the caret stands for. On my keyboard it is on the bottom left of the keyboard. CTRL stands for control, which is what is written on the key. If that doesn't work, try checking the System Preferences to see if it is enabled.